# Keep my hands warm while working on a laptop?

Tags: energy-efficiency, heating, reuse

I want to keep my hands warm(er) while working on a laptop in a cold room. Would it make sense to take a polar fleece blanket, fold it in half, sew together the two edges that are perpendicular to the fold, cut a slot in the middle two thirds of the fold, use it to create a sort of "enclosure" covering hands, mouse and keyboard with an open slot facing me?

Same question with one of those hot/cold insulated shopping bags, or other similar things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use a pair of wool fingerless gloves.  They don't impair dexterity and even though they leave fingers exposed they cover enough that my entire hands remain comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with using such "blanket" as you describe is that it can also insulate the keyboard. If you are using a desktop computer that may be okay, but it you are using a laptop computer you risk overheating the computer through insulating it and also possibly  restricting or blocking the exhaust vent for the computer.

Like Jean-Paul Calderone states, fingerless gloves are a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Put your hands under the laptop, laptops dispose of waste heat with their fan systems It's very warm.
Another trick, microwave a mug of water til it boils then seal plastic wrap so it cant spill.......instant hand warmer